# netconf device datastore path to subscribe for notifications

Tags: opendaylight

I have followed below link and it works without any issues in getting notifications from a toaster module.
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/developer-guide/controller.html

But the issue iam stuck is to find out, how i can create a notification stream from NorthBound of ODL for a netconf device which is mounted beyond yang-ext mount point in my operational datastore (i used netconf testool and test.yang file as my model).

To be more specific how one can determine the exact path of the netconf device in yang datatore - toaster path as an example is pasted below from developers guide:

---

The RPC to create the stream can be invoked via RESTCONF like this:

URI: http://{odlAddress}:{odlPort}/restconf/operations/sal-remote:create-data-change-event-subscription

```
DATA:
{
"input": {
**My problem -----> "path": "/toaster:toaster/toaster:toasterStatus",**
"sal-remote-augment:datastore": "OPERATIONAL",
"sal-remote-augment:scope": "ONE"
}
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: I found some more info that i could use atleast /network-topology:network-topology as "path" and could listen to notifications but it only gives me notifications of whether device is added/removed whether i use OPERATIONAL - SUBTREE,BASE or ONE. I still need to figureout how how i can listen to my container in the model which is at /network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/sampleNode. Does Opendaylight support netconf notifications NB to ODL for yangmodels which are not native but mounted beyond yang-ext:mount ?

Comment: I found how to give exact path but ultimately no notifications getting generated on the leaf of container apart from node connected/disconnected. If anyone is interested the path goes something like this 
        "path": "/network-topology:network-topology/network-topology:topology[network-topology:topology-id='topology-netconf']/network-topology:node[network-topology:node-id='yug1']"
        So mostly i beleive there is no notification support NB of ODL when a leaf gets updated inside a container, so not sure how Apps running on top of ODL can monitor alarms on netconf devices.

Comment: I found the answer in a hardway but hope this helps someone who is looking for netconf notification support. "RESTCONF does not support notifications from mounted NETCONF devices." --->https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/developer-guide/netconf-developer-guide.html